# Horror short. Man imagines saving his wife and child from drowning

Tags: story-identification

My favorite short ever describes a man (story told in first person) who relives over and over different scenarios of him jumping off a pier to save his wife and child from drowning in a lake. His memory in each recollection is in vivid detail but each time is a little different. At the end he relives the car crash that killed his family as they traveled to the lake. His guilt over causing the wreck had blocked the truth as he lived scenarios of attempts to save his family from drowning.
Please help me find the title of the story or anthology book. It was classified as either horror or science fiction.

Comment: What about this story is actually science fiction or fantasy? It just sounds like a guilt-ridden man fantasising.